# Не запускается драйвер скомпилированный на mingw64

Tags: c, mingw, windows-8, драйвер

Пытаюсь написать драйвер для Windows 8.1 на mingw64

**DriverMinGW.c:**

```
#include <ntddk.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath);
VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject);


NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
  DriverObject->DriverUnload = UnloadRoutine;

  KdPrint("Hello world!\n");

  return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
  KdPrint("Goodbye!\n");
}
```

**Далее пишу makefile:**

```
OBJECTS = DriverMinGW.o
TARGET = DriverMinGW.sys
CFLAGS = -I D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk -DMINGW -std=c99 -Wall -m64 -shared
CC = gcc

all: $(TARGET)

%.o: %.c clean
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -Wl,--subsystem,native -Wl,--image-base,0x10000 \
    -Wl,--file-alignment,0x1000 -Wl,--section-alignment,0x1000 \
    -Wl,--entry,DriverEntry@8 -Wl,--stack,0x40000 -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat \
    -nostartfiles -nostdlib -o $(TARGET) \
    $(OBJECTS) -lntoskrnl -lhal

clean:
    cmd //C del $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
```

После этого имею файл **DriverMinGW.sys**

На VMware установлен активированный windows 8.1 в тестовом режиме что бы не просил цифровую подпись драйвера.

Для загрузки и запуска драйвера я использую программу **OSR Driver Loader**
И при запуске драйвера вылетает ошибка о цифровой подписи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот я не понимаю. То ли с драйвером проблема. То ли в windows все таки требуется эта подпись. Объясните мне что я делаю не так?